# PostgreSQL user account expiry

Tags: postgresql, security, authentication, database-administration, user-management

I wonder is there any way to disable user account based on date.
The goal is to simply lock the account on timed schedule, not expire password.

Comment: `alter role ... valid until ...`?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html

Comment: isn't it password expiery? We are using LDAP auth, no point of expiring in-database passwords.

Comment: If you are using LDAP, then you need to expire the user in the LDAP server, not in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can store the time at which the lock should be effective in the user's row and make the application that uses the database check whether this time is in the past and allow/refuse connection accordingly.

Comment: Sure, I can invent some sort of "additional users policy table" plus some "cron" to enforce those policies, but I was wondering if there's any "built-in" way(guess NO) or extension or 3rd party open-source tool to implement it. Also I want to deal not with "application" users, but with technicians, who connect directly to database.

Comment: There might be, but not that I know of. Sorry